# ActivatedRoute params is empty in CanActivate guard

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-guards

I have generic guard for many applications:

```
export class Guard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
    async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        const user = await this.authService.getUserAuthenticated();
        const hasPerm = user && user.hasPermission(route.data.app);
        if (!hasPerm) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login/' + this.route.snapshot.params.site, {}]);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

But `this.route.snapshot.params.site` is empty for route : `"/signin/macro/561"`.

the route declaration :

```
{ path: 'signin/:site/:token', loadChildren: 'src/app/auth/auth.module#AuthModule' },
```

Comment: You haven't set any guard on the route

Answer (score 0):

Try using ActivatedRoute and access the params as `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.site`.
Plus you're using ActivatedRouteSnapshot and trying to access the snapshot property of it, which will obviously be undefined because it doesn't have any such property. You can try directly accessing the params in that case.